# Using noconflict js in Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, magento

One bootstrap tab navigation panel is not working properly on my magento site because of the `jQuery.noConflict()` call that I have used in my custom JS file.

When I comment the `jQuery.noConflict()` line then my tab navigation works properly. However, I cannot comment that code because when I comment that line the main navigation doesn't work.

How can I make my tab navigation work without removing the `jQuery.noConflict()`? Thanks.

Comment: which error you got ?

Comment: I tried this in two different ways one is [this] (http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tab&stacked=h) and other one is [this] (http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tab_show&stacked=h).

Comment: In first method I am getting noting but my tabs are closing when I click on them instead of opening, in second method I am getting error called $(this).tab('show') the tab is not a function. Please note I tried with JQuery(this).tab('show') as well. am getting noting but my tabs are closing when I click on them instead of opening, in second method I am geting error called $(this).tab('show') the tab is not a function. Please note I tried with JQuery(this).tab('show') as well.

Comment: Make you sure that tab jquery file load after jquery file. and if you use combine js feature then please make it turn off.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Magento still uses prototype.js, change jQuery to $j

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

For more details [check this out](https://css-tricks.com/using-jquery-in-magneto/)

Comment: I tried this. I removed all my "jQuery" flags and replaced them with variables but no luck. issue is coming from "jQuery.noConflict(); " I cannot put it in my custom.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Using `noConflict()` should be fine, however I come across issues like this a lot with Magento.

I'm assuming you're definitely loading jQuery prior to your own jQuery script, etc.

I tend to find the most watertight way of ensuring your jQuery scripts don't cause issues is to wrap your scripts in an anoymous function:

```
(function($) {
    // Your jQuery script
})(jQuery);
```

As you can see, we're passing the jQuery object as an argument to our function. This means we can use `$` locally within the function without it conflicting with other scripts / frameworks / libraries, etc...